# Encode/Decode a picture in Hex

Tags: javascript, php, xml, image, encoding

A client (a job board) has asked me to do the following : 
Create a form, gather informations and create an xml file containing all those informations everytime a user fills out the form, easy enough.
So the client sent me an xml model and within this xml file there is an encoded picture and an encoded CV, both are encoded (it seems in HEX), and i cannot understand how to decode (or even encode under the same format for that matter) the piece of HEX.
Here are pieces of the xml fiel, I cannot post it entirely, you'll surely understand why.

```
<photo>
FFD8FFE10A1845786966000049492A000800000008000F010200040000004854430010010200150000006E0000001201030001000000010[.............]EF6A57F5A8E41EE594D62075FF8F77CFF00B1FF00D7A7C17D13B7FA99157FE0269C60E22E4D4DAB38A09E24788F5FF80D5B5B5FEE9ACE32E518AB6DFEDAD1F653FC2D57700FB23FFB1F9D5DB64289B4
</photo>
<cv>
255044462D312E340D0A25C8C9CACB0D0A372030206F626A0D0A3C3C2F54797065202F506167652F506172656E742033203020522F436F6E74656E74.......
</cv>
<extensionCv>.pdf</extensionCv>
```

And just to make it harder here are several points to take into consideration :

- This file is to be used to import informations into a software which has been developed especially for this company, I do not have access to it, and cannot get in touch with the company that designed it. The xml file has been created by this software as an export of a candidat file.
- I cannot encode it in base64 (it'd be too easy), it needs to be the same encoding.
- I need to be able to encode it in either js, or php (once im sure the software can decode if, i'll only need to encode, I won't need to decode anything).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [bin2hex](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php) PHP function to convert binary data into HEX string. Please check PHP documentation where you can find an example of bin2hex with reading a binary file

Comment: Thank you, I have been able to encode a picture in hex using bin2hex along with fopen, although how would you go to decode the picture ? Now I can decode it into binary and that fine but how would i construct the file ? or turn it in base64 ? I just want to make sure the file is encoded the same way.

Comment: You can use hex2bin to convert data to binary again, then file_put_contents to create a file with that binary data